# Start large HTML table rendering immediately at the client, before the whole table is received

Tags: php, html

I have a PHP script which takes a search query, queries mySQL and dynamically builds an HTML page and echoes it to the client. The page includes a table. While building each table row, further queries are performed so it is usual that building the whole table takes time on the server.

When trying it out on my local machine, the client begins to render the table immediately, even when not all table rows have been received. When I tried it on a company server, the table is rendered only when the whole table data is received. That results in a large delay without anything showing on the client screen.

So, (naively) I am guessing that the problem is either

-the client on the company computers is forced to wait until 
the whole table is received, before rendering anything

-the server sends back the HTML only when all PHP is parsed

Is there some solution to this?

Comment: How are you achieving this now on your local machine?

Comment: you must be having your table code in one variable, instead put normal table(html) and use php to print data into it. This will start rendering table html with the page load.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you possibly post here relevant parts of the code you already have?